# Шифрование по ГОСТ 28147-89 в bouncycastle java

Tags: java, шифрование

Прошу помочь найти примеры реализации шифрования ГОСТ 28147-89 в java. Нашел библиотеку bouncycastle, в ней курил GOST28147Engine, но не хватает опыта написать работающую программу по шифрованию с последующей дешифровкой.

Comment: в библиотеке разве не реализованы эти методы, которые вам нужны?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример класса, который может работать со стрингом и массивом byte[].

Вызов:

```
MnpGOST28147Encription encriptor = new MnpGOST28147Encription();
String originalString = "String to encode";
String encoded = encriptor.Encode(originalString, key);
String decoded = encriptor.Decode(encoded, key, Hex.decode(originalString).length);
```

Сам класс:

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.GOST28147Engine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;

public class MnpGOST28147Encription {

    public String Encode(String str, byte[] key) {
        return processEncoding(true, str, key);
    }

    public String Decode(String str, byte[] key) {
        return processEncoding(false, str, key);
    }

    public String Decode(String str, byte[] key, int length) {
        return processEncoding(false, str, key, length);
    }

    public byte[] Encode(byte[] str, byte[] key) {
        return processEncoding(true, str, key);
    }

    public byte[] Decode(byte[] str, byte[] key) {
        return processEncoding(false, str, key);
    }

    public byte[] Decode(byte[] str, byte[] key, int length) {
        return trimBytes(processEncoding(false, str, key), length);
    }

    public String processEncoding(boolean ende, String str, byte[] key) {
        byte[] bytes = processEncoding(ende, Hex.decode(str), key);
        return new String(Hex.encode(bytes));
    }

    public String processEncoding(boolean ende, String str, byte[] key, int length) {
        byte[] bytes = trimBytes(processEncoding(ende, Hex.decode(str), key), length);
        return new String(Hex.encode(bytes));
    }

    public byte[] processEncoding(boolean ende, byte[] inBytes, byte[] key) {
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CBCBlockCipher(
                new GOST28147Engine()));
        cipher.init(ende, new KeyParameter(key));
        byte[] outBytes = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(inBytes.length)];
        int len = cipher.processBytes(inBytes, 0, inBytes.length, outBytes, 0);
        try {
            cipher.doFinal(outBytes, len);
        } catch (CryptoException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
        }
        return outBytes;
    }

    public byte[] trimBytes(byte[] bytes, int length) {
        byte[] outBytesTrimmed = new byte[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            outBytesTrimmed[i] = bytes[i];
        }
        return outBytesTrimmed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, подскажите, является ли это решением проблемы или вы хотели дополнить вопрос?

Comment: Это является решение проблемы, но я смогу принять ответ только через день.